# I am implementing image-preview functionality but during that unable to reset relevant file input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**I am implementing image-preview functionality (for multiple hidden-browse buttons with dynamic ids) but during that unable to reset relevant file input**

**Everything working fine..**

HTML Part:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">

                              <?php 
                                 $prd_imgs_sql = "SELECT * FROM `ci_product_images` WHERE `added_by` = '".$this->session->userdata('user_id')."' AND `is_prod_submited` = '0'";
                                 $prd_imgs_res = $this->home->customQuery($prd_imgs_sql); 
                                   $chk_img = 1;
                                   foreach($prd_imgs_res as $res){

                                      if($res->prod_img != "" ){
                                          $prdImgThumb = BASE_URL.'uploads/productImages/150x150/'.$res->prod_img_thumb;
                                      }else{
                                          $prdImgThumb = BASE_IMAGE.'plbtn.jpg';
                                      } 

                                      if($res->prod_img_link != "" ){
                                          $prdImgLinkTxt = $res->prod_img_link;
                                          $prdImgLink = $res->prod_img_link;
                                      }else{
                                          $prdImgLinkTxt = '';
                                          $prdImgLink = BASE_IMAGE.'preview.png';
                                      }  
                              ?>  
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                          <img src="<?=$prdImgLink?>" class="img-responsive primg" id="preview_img_<?php echo $chk_img;?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                          <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLnk" placeholder="Image Url.." id="url_input_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" name="url_input[]" value="<?=$prdImgLinkTxt?>" autocomplete="off">
                                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-default findbtn" type="button" id="find_btn_<?php echo $chk_img;?>">Find</button>
                                              </span>
                                            </div><!-- /input-group -->
                                            <div class="err" id="valmsg_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" style="display: none;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-1">
                                          <h2 style="text-align: center;">Or</h2>
                                         </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                          <div class="form-group">   
                                             <img src="<?=$prdImgThumb?>" class="edi_prd_img rk" id="brws_btn_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" />
                                             <?php if($res->prod_img != "" ){ ?>
                                                   <a class="topright imgDelete" href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>admin/products/delete_prd_img/<?php echo base64_encode($res->id);?>" id="imgdel_<?php echo $chk_img;?>">X</a>
                                             <?php } ?>      
                                             <input type="file" name="prod_images[]" id="ip_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" class="hidBrws" style="display: none;" />
                                          </div>   
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                              <?php 
                                        $chk_img++;
                                   }   
                              ?>

                              <?php 
                                    while($chk_img<5){
                              ?>  
                                        <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <img src="<?php echo BASE_IMAGE."preview.png"; ?>" class="img-responsive primg" id="preview_img_<?php echo $chk_img;?>">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control imgLnk" placeholder="Image Url.." id="url_input_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" name="url_input[]" autocomplete="off">
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                  <button class="btn btn-default findbtn" type="button" id="find_btn_<?php echo $chk_img;?>">Find</button>
                                                </span>
                                              </div><!-- /input-group -->
                                              <div class="err" id="valmsg_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" style="display: none;"></div>
                                          </div>
                                           <div class="col-sm-1">
                                            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Or</h2>
                                           </div>
                                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">   
                                               <img src="<?php echo BASE_IMAGE."plbtn.jpg"; ?>" class="edi_prd_img rk" id="brws_btn_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" />
                                               <input type="file" name="prod_images[]" id="ip_<?php echo $chk_img;?>" class="hidBrws" style="display: none;" />
                                            </div>   
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                              <?php 
                                        $chk_img++;
                                      }
                              ?>    
                            </div>
```

My jQuery Script:

```
    $(".edi_prd_img").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var tmp = id.split('_');
        $("input[id='ip_"+tmp[2]+"']").click();
    });

    $(".hidBrws").change(function() { 
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) { 
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var tmp = id.split('_');

          reader.onload = function(e) {   
              $('#preview_img_'+tmp[1]).attr('src','<?=base_url()?>preview.png');
              $('#url_input_'+tmp[1]).val('');           
              $('#brws_btn_'+tmp[1]).attr('src', e.target.result);
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
```

**But when I want to reset one of the browse-button (file) on some specific event then I am getting issue.. its not getting reset.**

My browse-button (file) reset jquery script:

```
$('.imgLnk').keyup(function(e){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     var tmp = id.split('_');
     $('ip_'+tmp[2]).val(''); //tried with this but not happening
     $('#brws_btn_'+tmp[2]).attr('src', '<?=base_url()?>plbtn.jpg');
     $('#imgdel_'+tmp[2]).hide();
});
```

But relevant reset jquery script not working..

not working: `$('ip_'+tmp[2]).val('');`

please suggest me changes or any idea

Comment: Is your `$('ip_'+tmp[2])` line giving correct identifier element?

Comment: yes.. its giving accurate id

Comment: Could you please share your HTML part as well so that we can debug it easily?

Comment: @MayankPatel I've added it in question.. check once

Comment: Please check my answer. You have a slight issue in your syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one issue with your code. You need to change your line `$('ip_'+tmp[2]).val('');` to `$('#ip_'+tmp[2]).val('');`. As this is your identifier, you have slight issue in syntax.

I just have updated your code to static code and created the fiddle. Try below. For testing purpose, I have enabled the file input.

```js
$(function(){
$('.imgLnk').keyup(function(e){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     var tmp = id.split('_');
     $('#ip_'+tmp[2]).val(''); //tried with this but not happening
     $('#brws_btn_'+tmp[2]).attr('src', '<?=base_url()?>plbtn.jpg');
     $('#imgdel_'+tmp[2]).hide();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<img src="<?=$prdImgThumb?>" class="edi_prd_img rk" id="brws_btn_1" />
<input type="text" class="form-control imgLnk" placeholder="Image Url.." id="url_input_1" name="url_input[]" autocomplete="off">
<input type="file" name="prod_images[]" id="ip_1" class="hidBrws" style="display: block;" />
</div>
<div class="row">
<img src="<?=$prdImgThumb?>" class="edi_prd_img rk" id="brws_btn_2" />
<input type="text" class="form-control imgLnk" placeholder="Image Url.." id="url_input_1" name="url_input[]" autocomplete="off">
<input type="file" name="prod_images[]" id="ip_2" class="hidBrws" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```